# Large VBScript array yields 'Out of Memory' error

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript, multidimensional-array, out-of-memory

In Classic ASP (VBScript), if I try to create a large 2-dimensinal array, I get an "Out of Memory" error.  For example, this

```
DIM xxx : xxx = 10000
DIM yyy : yyy = 10000
REDIM aaa(xxx, yyy)
Response.End
```

yeilds this

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0007' 

Out of memory
```

Is their another data structure I can use that will work, or some other workaround?

(2010-01-27) UPDATE: Upon further investigation of this legacy code I'm working on, the array is sparse.  In other words, only a portion of the array place holders are needed.  Like this:

```
aaa(0, 0) = 1.23
aaa(101,12) = 1.57
aaa(3020,1200) = 2.58
etc.
```

I thought about changing things to store the values like this:

```
aaa(count) = "xxx,yyy,val"
```

and then using Split() to get val given x and y, but that requires a time-consuming loop through the array each time I know x and y.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: You'll need to give at least an example of what you want to do with this memory. Data structure depends on usage...

Comment: Are you expecting all elements to have some significant value or would the population of this array actually be quite sparse?

Comment: Actually, it will be quite sparse. (This is someone else's legacy code I'm working on, BTW.)  Can you think of a better storage mechanism?  I thought of using a flat array of triplets: array()="x,y,val" and then using Split() to get 'val' given x and y, but the retrieval process is slow.

Comment: find the original developer and kick his butt... says I ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a sparse array, use a nested `Scripting.Dictionary` to store it. This is probably the easiest and most efficient way in VBScript (barring a COM library for sparse arrays).

```
Set arr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Adding a column: '
Dim NewCol
NewCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr.Add row, NewCol

' Adding a value in an (existing!) row/column: '
If arr.Exists(row) Then _
    arr(row).Add column, value

' Retrieving a value: '
? arr(row)(column)
```

Answer (score 11):

You're trying to redimension the array to 10000 x 10000, which is 100,000,000 elements.

This is an array of Variants, which requires a single, contiguous 1.525 GB chunk of space, just to hold that array.  If you're doing other work in the application, and running in 32bit, you're going to be limited to 2GB total for your process space.  Trying to get a chunk that large is problematic.

In general, I would avoid trying to do allocations this large in a web-based application.  This should be saved in the database, and the data paged out as necessary.  If you need to do processing on the data, do it in a separate service, not in ASP.

Comment: +1 The array will be always be an array of Variants which are 16 bytes in size hence about 1.5GB is being allocated.